# Is there a way to convert this to rails arel queries? Or a better way to do this query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 tables: groups, users and posts. Posts have a user_id and Users have a group_id. I'd like to find out which group has the top poster between a date range, preferably only using ActiveRecord. I think this query does the job:

```
select g_id, count(p_id) as posts_count 
from (
  select users.group_id as g_id, posts.id as p_id 
  from users inner join posts 
  on users.id = posts.user_id 
  where users.group_id is not null
  and posts.created_at > :since
  and posts.created_at <= :until
) as foo 
group by g_id 
order by posts_count desc limit 1;
```

Can someone help me translate it to ruby?

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in few steps.
First - get count of posts, grouped by group_id.

```
posts = Post.includes(
        :user
    ).where(
        'users.group_id is not null'
    ).where(
        :posts => {:created_at => ('12.09.2011'.to_date)..('12.09.2012'.to_date)}
    ).group(
        :group_id
    ).count
```

It will return a hash like `{1=>4, 2=>5, 3=>2}`, where key is a id of group, and value is count of posts.

Then you need to sort this hash, and get last element of array.

```
sorted_hash = posts.sort_by {|key,value| value}
top_posters_group = sorted_hash[-1]
```

After that, `top_posters_group[0]` will be a id of group, and `top_posters_group[1]` is count of posts.

But anyway this isn't ideal solution.

Tested in rails 3.1 with ruby 1.9.2.